# deleting accents and spaces from URLs

Tags: php, urlencode

hello: i'm trying to optimize my Urls, using urlencode() it works fine using "+" instead of %20 in the spaces, but some names has uppercase and latin characters, offcourse they are not any frinedly, then i've tried using this function to use only lowercase and replacing latin characters in the url:

```
function delete_accent($texto){   
$texto=utf8_decode($texto);
$con_acento = utf8_decode("ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ");
$sin_acento = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeCcIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuyNn";
$texto= strtr($texto, $con_acento, $sin_acento);
$texto = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 _]/","",$texto);

//all to lowercase

$texto = strtolower(trim ($texto));
//replacing %20 to -
$texto = preg_replace( array("`[^a-z0-9]`i","`[-]+`") , "-", $texto);
return $texto;
}

<a href="actividad.php?nombre=<?php echo urlencode(delete_accent($row->nombre)) ?>">¡ VER MÁS !</a>
```

that link does not work, cause actividad.php is not getting a valid name from the DB. How can i eliminate the latin accents and uppercase from the URLs, i've been searching but i have this link that can't work using the solutions founded.

Comment: add a second field to your database nombreurl and fill with delete_accent(nombre). use this in "actividad.php

Comment: thanks! i think i might have to do that, seems that there isnt a way to mask the url with those characteres. thanks for your answer.